# what is the default Cacheability of a page ? asp.net IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, browser-cache, httpbrowsercapabilities

After having [this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431) on our websites over secure SSL connections for Office file download with `Cacheability` setting. I am wondering what would be the correct setting to use.

If I completely remove this following line of code, what would be the default `Cacheability` for the page? I have read the following [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9s3a17d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so if i set nothing what would be the default?

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)
```

If I can't use `No-cache` then shall I use private or public safely then setting nothing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Private" is the default value for the cache.